# how to take out an existing textbox value and add it with other value and display the output in the same textbox

Tags: jquery, textbox

hi i am creating a form which consist of calculation but i came across a problem which i am not being able to solve it the problem is i have a textbox which will display the some numeric values and i want to add some value to its existing value and want to display the value in the same textbox For e.g
if the value in the textbox is '10' and i want to add more 10 which will result '10+10' and will show the output 20 in the same textbox 
here is my code

```
   var mbill = $("#billamt").val();// this will have a default value
    $(".cal").each(function() {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            bill += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });

     var finalamt = mbill + bill;
    console.log(finalamt);
     $("#billamt").val(finalamt.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: What is the current result?

Comment: the current result comes nothing

Comment: check firebug/console to see whether is there any errors?

Comment: the firebug isnt showing any error but its showing the proper output

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a variable out of scope, but hard to tell exactly without all of your code. Where is the variable `bill` declared? You also need to parse the `mbill` variable so it doesn't get treated as text.

Is this what you're after?

```
<input class=cal type=text /><br />
<input class=cal type=text /><br />
<br /><br />
<input id=numtoadd type=text value=10 /><br />

var mbill = parseFloat($("#numtoadd").val());

$(".cal").keyup(function(){
    var bill = 0;

    $(".cal").each(function(){
        if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val().length != 0) {
            bill += parseFloat($(this).val());          
        }
    });
    $("#numtoadd").val(mbill + bill);
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MTgpN/2/

Comment: nopes the function cal will get the total of the values above and want to add it with the my existing value dynamically and show the output in the same textbox

Comment: @user2274075 Think i might understand a bit better, changed code and updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var bill;
 var mbill = $("#billamt").val();// this will have a default value
    $(".cal").each(function() {
        if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val().length != 0) {
            bill += parseFloat($(this).val());
        }
    });

 var finalamt = mbill + bill;
console.log(finalamt);
 $("#billamt").val(finalamt.toFixed(2))
```